# itemize environment in tabularx with \hsize adjustment doesn't fill the whole width

Tags: tabularx, itemize, width

I wanted to have a small `itemize` environment for tabulars, with small spaces to the top and bottom. I found a good example, but not fully understand the mbox setting:

```
\newenvironment{tabitem}{
    \begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet, nolistsep, leftmargin=10pt,
            before*={\mbox{}\vspace{-\baselineskip}}]
}
{\end{itemize}\vspace*{1.0 em}}
```

Until now it was no problem, but now I wanted to use that environment inside a `tabularx` environment with `\hsize` adjustment and `\hsize>1.0`. That gave me the problem, that the `itemize` environment doesn't use the full size of the row.

I thought it was the `\mbox{}` in the definition. But removing it doesn't changed the behaviour.

Is there a possibility to fix that?

Here is my mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{tabitem}{
    \begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet, nolistsep, leftmargin=10pt,
            before*={\mbox{}\vspace{-\baselineskip}}]
}
{\end{itemize}\vspace*{1.0 em}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=0.2\hsize}X >{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=1.8\hsize}X}

        \textbf{small row} &
        \textbf{a very long row to demonstrate the actual length of the row}\\
            
        %\midrule
    
        1 &
        \begin{tabitem}
            \item A very long sentence, just to demonstrate what happens inside the itemize environment if you exceed the default length of the table columns, even though the width has been adjusted in the table settings
        \end{tabitem}\\
        
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: add `\linewidth=\hsize` after each of the `\hsize` settings

Comment: That works perfectly! Can you make an answer out of that, that I can mark it as a solution?

Comment: it's probably a dup, let me look...

Comment: Thanks. Couldn't found that, because I thought the problem was the `itemize` environment.

Comment: It's always easier to search for the answer rather than the question:-) https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btabularx%5D+%5Clinewidth%3D%5Chsize+user%3A1090